# Small actuators/motors to generate low frequency vibrations

Tags: motor, frequency, actuator

I am a beginner in vibration technology, and I am interested in making a wearable device that delivers low-frequency and low-amplitude vibrations to the user's wrist. All of the motors I have found vibrate at a frequency that is too high for my project.  The vibrations have to be small enough to not be easily noticed by the user (ideally 1 hz or under).  Are these frequencies possible to achieve with small commercial motors/actuators?  If not, is there a way to create these vibrations? Thank you!

Comment: _" The vibrations have to be small enough to not be easily noticed by the user (ideally 1 hz or under)."_- No problem, just use a geared motor with output speed of 60rpm. Of course if you don't use a huge weight the vibrations will definitely be small enough to not be easily noticed by the user - which seems pointless, but I guess you have a reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PWM to pulse the vibrators that go too fast.  If you just send a short pulse every second, it feels like 1 Hz.

The idea is you set the frequency electronically instead of relying on the speed of the vibrator.

For example: You turn on the motor for 0.1 seconds, then turn it off for 0.9 seconds, and just loop that.

This is the technique used in game controller vibrators to simulate, for instance, a heart beat effect.

You could also use PWM to speed up and slow down the motor on a 1 Hz cycle.  Where the speed of the motor looks like a sine wave if you were to graph it.

Comment: A short "pulse" will have lots of high frequency content, unlike a 1 Hz sinusoid. The user would feel that as a jerking sensation once per second.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Very true, and good point.  Unfortunately a 1 Hz sinusoid fed to the motor won't produce the desired result either, so this is the closest I could come up with to achieve the effect.  Since the method of action with these is an off-balance weight, slowing the motor to 1 rev per second (if even possible) wouldn't produce the desired effect either.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into spring mass damper systems. If you need your device to operate at 1 Hz you should try to design your mechanical system using the following equation:
\begin{equation}
f_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt\frac{k}{m}
\end{equation}
Where K is your spring stiffness, and m is your mass.

For rotational systems you use a similar equation:
\begin{equation}
f_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt\frac{q}{I}
\end{equation}
where q is your torsional stiffness and I is your mass moment of inertia.

If you make your mechanical system have a 1 Hz frequency then all you need to do is provide periodic impulses using a magnetic solenoid to get the system moving.